# Javapop up for sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have developed a sharepoint custom webpart. How do I show it in a javascript pop up when i click on a link at my share point site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a webpart page first, deploy your webpart in this page and set your popup page as this 
web part page.

from our project, we develop an application page and popup it instead of your way.

Comment: But this would take a lot of time as we are loading a fresh page during pop up. Isn't there some quicker method?